# How to handle with webdrivers in visual studio code Protractor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was getting an error

> WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
>       from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
>         (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

I updated the Visual Studio Code a few days ago. Now i think that it is incompatible with ChromeDriver. I'm using chrome76.

Before updating VS code it was working correctly But now it gives that error. I searched on everywhere on net
Some of them telling that upgrade chrome driver etc. Kindly upload complete procedure how to check for software and how to handle that.

Comment: Did you update the webdriver using command 

"npm update protractor -g"

"webdriver-manager update"

Comment: yes i using npm install -g prtractor and  webdriver-manager update

Comment: Then there is a problem with the chrome version try down grade your chrome version to 75 and try again.

Comment: what about the chrome driver it self?

Comment: Did you update the chrome driver?

Comment: using command npm install chromedriver / npm update chromedriver

Comment: done it shows that chrome drivers installed 76.etc

Comment: but giving me same error thatWebDriverError: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
    from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
      (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Is this error displaying during test execution or before execution?

Comment: when i enter protractor conf.js it open google chrome for a few second and then it shows that error in the terminal And Another thing that when i use different browser line Mozilla by using in Config file capibilites and set browser to firefox same that programs Runs...

Comment: There must be compatibility issue if it is working in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are still having old version of chromedriver=2.27.440174 , you should update protractor to use latest version of chromedriver_76.0.3809.12.zip

Try Updating Webdriver Manager:

```
 webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: I wait for few hours,relax and then update the webdriver by adding chrome driver in bin and also with webdriver-manager update command he updated chromedriver .Now its started working to first 2 test cases but in the 3 test case or Onward it shows that error    Failed: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.100)
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: `webdriver-manager update` was not updating chromedriver version in local `npm_module` for me, I tried following steps : explained in [Protractor issue with chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484124/protractor-issue-with-chromedriver-versions-like-76-0-3809-12/57499194#57499194)

Answer (score 0):

webdriver-manager update is the command that will automatically update the Chrome driver But some time is not update Because of slow performance For that i Shutdown my PC, after few hours it updated Automatically