# How to update webdriver-manager (spawn Unknown system error -86)

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, npm, dependencies, protractor

(Angular). `webdriver-manager 12.1.7` has known issues on intel based Macs. Running `e2e` tests we get the following error: `spawn Unknown system error -86`. This bug has been fixed in `webdriver-manager 12.1.8` but I'm unable to update.

I've tried the solutions listed here (reinstalling Protractor, etc): [OSX fix Selenium Chromedriver launch error spawn Unknown system error -86 Bad CPU type in executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618558/osx-fix-selenium-chromedriver-launch-error-spawn-unknown-system-error-86-bad-cp)

However, after uninstalling and re-installing `protractor`, nothing changes. When I look in `package-lock.json`, it appears that we're still using `webdriver-manager 12.1.7` rather than the desired `12.1.8`. How can I force update webdriver-manager from `12.1.7` to `12.1.8`? We have an `npm run webdriver-update` command which calls `webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false` - this too fails to change the version (if I'm reading package-lock.json correctly).

**package-lock.json**

```
"node_modules/protractor": {
  "version": "7.0.0",
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
 },
 "bin": {
    "protractor": "bin/protractor",
    "webdriver-manager": "bin/webdriver-manager"
     }

....


"protractor": {
   "version": "7.0.0",
 },
"dependencies": {
    "webdriver-manager": {
      "version": "12.1.7",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webdriver-manager/-/webdriver-manager-12.1.7.tgz",
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like v7.0.0 is set to use `webdriver-manager v12.1.7` in the package.json for protractor. So that would be why it's not updating to 12.1.8. You can see it listed as a dependency [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/df3dd6400e3a4792ff9f7a58849d2a5eed6e1483/package.json#L29).

You can try doing something like what I posted on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484124/protractor-issue-with-chromedriver-versions-like-76-0-3809-12#answer-57513975) to a similar question.

Basically, switch to your `./node_modules/protractor` folder, run `npm i webdriver-manager@12.1.8`, then switch back to app root and run `webdriver-manager update`. It should pull in all the right drivers for you.

---

Another solution you could try is to just delete the package-lock.json file from your directory and run `npm install` again. It may pull down the version you are looking for. The lock file will get recreated and it may update the webdriver-manager version.